# Как отправить сообщение в aiogram после обработки callback?

Tags: python, aiogram

Пишу диалог с ботом с помощью FSM.
В процессе диалога, после обработки нажатия inlain кнопки, нужно отправить сообщение. Но метод answer отправляет уведомление, а не сообщение.

```
await call.answer("спрашиваю вопрос ?:")
```

я знаю, что можно отправить сообщение
await bot.send_message("спрашиваю вопрос ?:") но мне это не очень подходит, так как объект bot формируется в главном скрипте в функции main. что бы было понятней прикрепляю код:
скрипт main

```
async def main():
    # Объявление и инициализация объектов бота и диспетчера
    bot = Bot(token=settings.API_TOKEN)
    storage = RedisStorage2('localhost', 6379, db=5, pool_size=10, prefix='my_fsm_key')
    dp = Dispatcher(bot, storage=storage)

    # Регистрация хэндлеров
    register_handlers_common(dp)
    register_handlers_lowprice(dp)

    # Установка команд бота
    await set_commands(bot)

    # Запуск поллинга
    await dp.skip_updates()  # пропуск накопившихся апдейтов (необязательно)
    await dp.start_polling()
```

скрипт lowprice с проблемой.

```
class HotelOrder(StatesGroup):
    waiting_for_city_name_l = State()
    waiting_for_city_answer_l = State()
    waiting_for_hotel_number_l = State()
    waiting_for_photo_number_l = State()
    waiting_for_history_saving_l = State()


async def hotels_start(message: types.Message):
    message_text = f'введите название города'
    await message.answer(message_text)
    await HotelOrder.waiting_for_city_name_l.set()


async def hotels_buttons(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    тут формируется инлайн клавиатура


async def city_name_chosen(call: types.CallbackQuery, state: FSMContext):
    if call.data[4:] =='red':
        await call.answer("давай по новой миша.")
        return
    await state.update_data(city_id=call.data[4:]) 
    await call.answer("Cпрашиваю вопрос ?:") # код выводит уведомление, а не сообщение.
    await HotelOrder.next()
    await HotelOrder.waiting_for_hotel_number_l.set()


async def hotel_count_chosen(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    код опущен для краткости


async def photo_count_chosen(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    код опущен для краткости


async def history_chosen(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    код опущен для краткости


def register_handlers_lowprice(dp: Dispatcher):
    dp.register_message_handler(hotels_start, commands="lowprice", state="*")
    dp.register_message_handler(hotels_buttons, state=HotelOrder.waiting_for_city_name_l)
    dp.register_callback_query_handler(city_name_chosen, state=HotelOrder.waiting_for_city_answer_l)
    dp.register_message_handler(hotel_count_chosen, state=HotelOrder.waiting_for_hotel_number_l)
    dp.register_message_handler(photo_count_chosen, state=HotelOrder.waiting_for_photo_number_l)
    dp.register_message_handler(history_chosen, state=HotelOrder.waiting_for_history_saving_l)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это не сложно просто нужно обратится к объекту measage который находится в call.

```
await call.message.answer("text")
```

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку!